# How to reload/refresh a fragment from a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an android application that uses navigation drawer. 
I followed this tutorial [Naviation Drawer Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

and able to work with this on my **MainActivity.java**

I have this code in **MainActivity** to set the fragment I want to show:

```
public void displayView(int position) throws Exception {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new EventsFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Now in my **EventsFragment.java** I have this code to reload the fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
        MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();
        try {
                    // reload and set the displayValue position to 1 = EventsFragment()
            mainAct.displayView(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed.
```

I believe I got this error in this part of code: 
`fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reference to the parent `Activity`, use `Fragment.getActivity()`

```
@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
    Activity mainAct = getActivity();

    // Make sure the host Activity is infact an instance of MainActivity, and has displayView()
    if(mainAct instanceof MainActivity) {
        mainAct.displayView(1);
    }
}
```